# mySQL PDO not able to SELECT from TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I am trying to learn mySQL PDO .. read tutorial after tutorial and trying to apply different ways to perform a simple SELECT statement.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
<?
include("inc/connPDO.php"); // hostname, username and password and dbName are in here
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
echo 'Connected to database';   // this outputs appropriately

/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rofWeapons";
echo '<p>'.$sql;
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){   // *** line 11 error 
    print $row['weaponName'] .' - '. $row['weaponType'] . '<br />';
}


/*** close the database connection ***/
$dbh = null;    
}
    catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

The output is the following:

> Connected to database
>
> SELECT * FROM rofWeapons
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/path/to/script/script.php on line 11

I am following a tutorial.. the foreach looks good.  Why is it an invalid argument?

When I enter "SELECT * FROM rofWeapons" into mySQL queries the table perfectly fine.

A little help please?

**Another Attempt**

If I try a PREPARE statement:

```
/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
$weaponType=1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rofWeapons WHERE weaponType=:weaponType";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);   // *** error Line 12 ***
$stmt->bindValue(':weaponType', $weaponType, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print $row['weaponName'] .' - '. $row['weaponType'] . '<br />';
    }
```

I get no error.  Nothing at all.

This is very frustrating.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not fetching the array...

Comment: @Mr.Alien The code is correct. See the 1st example here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: print_r($dbh->query($sql)) What is the result?

Comment: print_r($dbh->query($sql)); returns nothing...

Comment: can someone throw me some code so I can understand the structure a little better please? i have read a number of tutorials and the PHP.NET resources.  I just can't get it to work... error after error despite multiple attempts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not fetched the array for using in the loop.

Change:

```
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){
    //YOUR CODE STUFF
}
```

To:

```
foreach ($dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll as $row){
    //YOUR CODE STUFF
}
```

It works fine.

Comment: I appreciate that but I still get an error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... line 11.  Can there be something wrong with my server PHP settings? I have been trying for over a month to get PDO working.. I just get error after error.

Comment: Hope your table having record in it.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?  there are records in the table.. when I manually enter the SELECT in the command line it works

Comment: Ok. Then make sure you are connected to database properly. again print_r($dbh);

Comment: Also make sure that your db params like host, database etc are given correctly.

Comment: What is the result of `print_r($dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this would fix your problem but you may want to try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rofWeapons";
$sth = $dbh->query($sql);
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
     print $row['weaponName'] .' - '. $row['weaponType'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: that gives me this error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in